# .Net Hiddenfield not rendering on client

Tags: asp.net

I put an asp.net hiddenfield into one of my pages. I couldn't access it through javascript and when I went to view source, I couldn't find it in the page at all. Is there any obvious reason for this?
Here's the line with the hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenEmailAddress" runat="server" Value="test" />
```

The problem was that the hiddenfield was placed in a table that was invisible at the time. Will self answer when system allows.

Comment: Can you include your source from the asp.net page? Off the top of my head, i'd suggest making sure you don't have Visible set to true for the control.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache, etc?

Comment: Clearing browser cache wouldn't have any effect on what HTML was generated by asp.net, which is the problem he's having. The browser wouldn't cache HTML like that, would it? That would be a first for me.

Comment: nothing so obvious that I can tell without seeing any of your code ;)

Comment: Here's the line with the hidden field:                             <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenEmailAddress" runat="server" Value="test" /> The rest of the page is too big.

Comment: @nlehman: Always edit the question itself not a comment to provide code (or more infos in general).

Comment: What @nlehman said... So, the next thing I would check is to make sure you don't have your HiddenField inside a container that has its visibility set to false.

Comment: Got it. The problem was that the hiddenfield was placed in a table row that was invisible. I have to wait 7 hours to self answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your control is inside of another control that has it's visibility set to false, but you already knew that. :D